# hibernate, created SQL query

Tags: hibernate

I have mapped class, that have ID with custom type

```
<id name="idPersistent" type="objectID" column="aa_id" > 
         <generator class="ObjectIDSequenceGenerator">
            <param name="sequence">lab_patient_seq</param>
         </generator>
      </id>
```

Field aa_id have type in DB

```
number(14)
```

My ID's sustom type have have types Long and ObjectID (ObjectID is my class).
(nullSafeGet return ObjectID, nullSafeSet return Long).

In SQL query, created by hibernate, i have next

```
select patient0_.aa_id as aa1_1224_1_ ...... and patient0_.aa_id=?
```

What type will be on "?" position? Where from Hibernate get '?' value?

Comment: what code did you write in java to trigger this SQL?

Comment: Query is created by method merge()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be Long since Hibernate will use your UserType to get the value to compare to.